# Retrolambda 3.3 in Android Studio 2.1.3: error configuring project ':app'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrolambda

I configured my project (Module:app) in Android Studio 2.1.3 (Windows 7)
(plugin `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'`)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
       classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

retrolambda {
    jdk System.getenv("JAVA8_HOME")
    oldJdk System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME")
    javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
android {    
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.enterprise"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config        
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
....
```

And I got

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

I use Facebook and Twitter (fabric) dependencies.

I removed `apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'` and it runs ok but without retrolambda.

I tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251071/retrolambda-error-when-adding-facebook-sdk-4-android-studio

  - I removed Facebook. Same issue.
- [Android Studio graddle 2.1.3 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000831/android-studio-graddle-2-1-3-issue)

  - I added `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3'`
- [In Android Studio 2.1.3 is experimental gradle not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007609/in-android-studio-2-1-3-is-experimental-gradle-not-working)
- https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/issues/17

I got this in the IDE log

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
.....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.tatarka.RetrolambdaPluginAndroid.configureCompileJavaTask(RetrolambdaPluginAndroid.groovy:74)
    at me.tatarka.RetrolambdaPluginAndroid.access$3(RetrolambdaPluginAndroid.groovy)
    at me.tatarka.RetrolambdaPluginAndroid$_apply_closure5.doCall(RetrolambdaPluginAndroid.groovy:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
    at org.gradle.listener.ActionBroadcast.execute(ActionBroadcast.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:165)
```

Comment: Waiting for the answer, I decided to use https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API
( https://medium.com/@nicopasso/java-8-stream-on-android-c629e4237d5f#.oe6avr5fx )

Comment: The same trouble. I tried to use retrolambda but got the same result. Without plugin it`s compiled well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that same problem, update [Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) to version 3.5.0.

In your root build.gradle type this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    ...
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3"
     classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.5.0'
  }
}

//At the end of the file place this:
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

In your module app build.gradle type this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
            jackInProcess false
        }
    }
}

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    incremental false
}

//it needs to translate the Java 8 code we write in the Java 7/ Java 6 bytecode Android understands:
retrolambda {
    jdk System.getenv('JAVA8_HOME')
    oldJdk System.getenv('JAVA7_HOME')
    jvmArgs '-arg1', '-arg2'
    defaultMethods false
   incremental true
}
```

You can use [this utility](https://gist.github.com/Takhion/5c0f6c0c5aba9db5a488) to the query the Java installation, asking for the path of the version we submitted as a input parameter.